# Unicode for registered trademark not displaying properly in Android string?

Tags: android, string, unicode

I want to display the symbol ® in my string, for which i have added a unicode in the string file. but it does not look like what i have expected the symbol should be small and to the power to application string. i have tried the same in a POC in a hello world string and there it is working fine, it is difficult to investigate the while the line of code is same for both the application.

this is what i have written in strings:

```
<string name="helloworld">Hello World <sup><small>&#174;</small></sup></string>
```

Hello World ® this is what i got as result where the expected one in different.

**P.S EXPECTED RESULT IS GIVE BELOW :**

[image]

Comment: can you put the expected result here ?

Comment: @ManishKarena : added the expected result in question.

Answer (score 0):

Make your textview like this:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/helloworld"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>
```

And your string like below:

```
<string name="helloworld">Hello World <sup><b>&#xae;</b></sup></string>
```

Comment: i have tried this , but it dosent gives me the expected result.